# Raspberry pi only allocate 9GB to /dev/root where more to other partitions

Tags: linux, filesystems, raspberry-pi, kali-linux

I've been trying to flash kali Linux OS on my raspberry Pi 4 device using Raspberry Pi imager, where It's setting only 9.3GB to be the main storage where I can't install my tools and run my scripts, Given below is output of my storage.

```sh
kali@kali:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       9.3G  9.0G     0 100% /
devtmpfs        3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.6G  928K  1.6G   1% /run
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
/dev/mmcblk0p1  126M   74M   52M  59% /boot
tmpfs           782M   56K  782M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Is there anyways by which I can merg the unused devtmpf,tmpfs to my main /dev/root Filesystem?

Comment: How did you obtain Kali Linux for Raspberry Pi?

Comment: It's available on kali's official site arm version.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your SD card is >9GB, you will have to resize the root partition to take up the remaining space on the card.

You would usually do this with the `raspi-config` utility however if that is not available you could try [gparted](https://gparted.org/) instead.

Check this [gist](https://gist.github.com/jgamblin/2441964a1266764ed71f3243f87bbeec) for instructions on how to instlal `raspi-config` on Kali Linux:

```
apt-get update
apt install lua5.1 alsa-utils psmisc && apt --fix-broken install

wget http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/pool/main/r/rpi-update/rpi-update_20200409_all.deb
wget http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/pool/main/r/raspi-config/raspi-config_20201108_all.deb
dpkg -i rpi-update_20200409_all.deb raspi-config_20201108_all.deb
```

Comment: SD card is 64 GB

Comment: Note: 59.5 GiB =~ 63.8GB, which rounds to 64.   I hate marketing people.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed! - after using the Raspberry Pi Imager to do a base install of the light Raspberry Pi OS. The option to expand the partition was in raspi-config under advanced options.

Answer (score 0):

The devtmpfs and tmpfs filesystems are in RAM and not on your sd card, and can't be merged as you suggest.

You should examine the output of `lsblk` and `fdisk -l` rather than `df` to understand the configuration of your hardware.

Note that the left column of df is the device name.  This is somewhat misleading as `/dev/root` is a virtual device rather than the real device it covers.  The rest of the listed filesystems list their real device.

From your comment, it appears you have a 59G device but the partition is only 9.5G.  You should follow the advise in the other answer to resize it.

Comment: this is the output I got for the command

```sh
kali@kali:~$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
mmcblk0     179:0    0 59.5G  0 disk 
|-mmcblk0p1 179:1    0  127M  0 part /boot
`-mmcblk0p2 179:2    0  9.5G  0 part /
```

Comment: You should add that to the question, not a comment.